# MIPS loading words from specific point in an array

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I'm having trouble figuring out how to load not a single word but every word from an address that describes an array (in assembly language).  For example, if I have a word of 10 elements and I want every element from 0-4 (the first half) stored to a second address how would I go about this?

Comment: The question is not clear but I think he is looking for loading parts of a word, in that case your only choice is lb/lbu which loads a byte (1/4 of a word) into a register and sign-extends/zero-extends

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear but I think you are looking for loading parts of a word, in that case your only choice is lb/lbu which loads a byte (1/4 of a word) into a register and sign-extends/zero-extends